# Why does my modal shows all photos and not one?

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

Hi im having and issue with a modal in my view, it seems that it is not identifying the id im selecting and it is showing every uploaded photo but i only want to show the selected one.

So this is my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="DetalleTicketView" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="z-index: 1050; display:none; width:100%" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="max-width:75%;">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Remito</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-responsive" width="100%">
                            
                            <tbody>
                               
                                @foreach($file as $key => $detalleTicket)
                                <tr>                                   
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <img src="{{asset('storage/' . $detalleTicket->remitoCliente)}}" alt="">
                                
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        </div>




</section>
```

And this is the button i press so that the modal appears:

```
 <a title="Info" id="info" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-idUpdate="'.$detalleTicket->id.'" data-target="#DetalleTicketView"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

So now if i upload to different pictures and visualize one it shows me both of them one above the other one.

DetalleTicketController:

```
    class DetalleTicketController extends Controller
{
     public function view(){ 
       $file = DetalleTicket::all();
       return view('backend.detalle_ticket.view-detalle-ticket', compact('file'));
}

    public function add(){
      $detalleTicket['tickets'] = Ticket::all();        
      $detalleTicket['products'] = Product::all();
    
      return view('backend.detalle_ticket.add-detalle-ticket', $detalleTicket);
}

public function store(Request $request){
    /*dd($request->all());*/
    $detalleTicket = new DetalleTicket();

    $detalleTicket->ticket_id = $request->ticket_id;
    $detalleTicket->product_id = $request->product_id;
    $detalleTicket->serial_number = $request->serial_number;
    $detalleTicket->quantity = $request->quantity;
    $detalleTicket->commentary = $request->commentary;
    $path = request()->file('remitoCliente')->store('archivos'); 
    $detalleTicket->remitoCliente = $path;
    
    $detalleTicket->save();
    Session::flash('success');
    return redirect()->route('detalles-tickets.view', $path);
}

public function edit($id){
    $data['editData'] = DetalleTicket::find($id);
    $data['tickets'] = Ticket::all();
    $data['products'] = Product::all();
    
    
    return view('backend.detalle_ticket.edit-detalle-ticket', $data);
}

public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $detalleTicket = DetalleTicket::find($id);
    
           
    $detalleTicket->ticket_id = $request->ticket_id;
    $detalleTicket->product_id = $request->product_id;
    $detalleTicket->serial_number = $request->serial_number;
    $detalleTicket->quantity = $request->quantity;
    $detalleTicket->commentary = $request->commentary;
    $path = request()->file('remitoCliente')->store('archivos'); 
    $detalleTicket->remitoCliente = $path;
    
    $detalleTicket->save();
    
    Session::flash('success');
    return redirect()->route('detalles-tickets.view');
}

public function delete($id){
    $detalleTicket = DetalleTicket::find($id);
    $detalleTicket->delete();
    return redirect()->route('detalles-tickets.view');
}
```

}

Comment: You are using `@foreach($file)`, I believe, in $file variable you have all images. Not only the one you want

Comment: All your images are displayed because you are not using a function in your button that only retrieves the data that matches the desired id.

Comment: @Atika But i did the same with products and it this work

Comment: @Autista_z i edited the question and added my controller. Let me know if you cand find any mistake in there because to me it seems fine.

Comment: Your **view** function returns all the data, at no time do you use your `$id`, that's why all the images are displayed

Comment: So how should i do it? @Atika do you have any example? I tried doing public function view(Request $request, $id){ $detalleTicket= DetalleTicket::find($id); } but it doesnt work

Comment: you say you did the same for products and it worked, what did you do differently ?
I'm used to using functions on buttons and it works very well for me

Comment: I did nothing different i used a for each for products and the same view button but the one in products didnt show images, it shows all the fields of the selected product. But it is the same logic i just want to use one field of the selected detalleTicket instead of every detalleTicket @Atika

Answer (score 0):

In your Modal, you are showing all images by default, becouse in `$file` variable you have all DetalleTickets.

You have to make some JS/jQuery changes to show only the image you want.

For example:
Add IDs to images

```
@foreach($file as $key => $detalleTicket)
    <tr class="modalImages" id="modalImage-{{ $detalleTicket->id }}">                                   
        <img src="{{asset('storage/' . $detalleTicket->remitoCliente)}}" alt="">
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

And in you jQuery after model open something like:

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    $('.modalImages').hide();
    $('#modalImage-' + $(this).data('idUpdate')).show();
});
```